# SWT RowLayout right-to-left?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I've read the article [Understand SWT Layout](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html), but I cannot find a way to put several buttons in a container in right-to-left way.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right to left can be achieved through SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT flag passed to your container element. For example if you apply a RowLayout to a Composite, create Composite this way:

```
c = new Composite(shell, SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Note that RTL is only implemented in Windows and Linux. Mac support is too limited (is only widget-level, not container-level).

Comment: Awesome, dude.. !